# Negative Binomial Regression model; algorithm did not converge

Tags: r, convergence, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

I am using R to run some negative binomial regression models. 
For model 1 I have the number of network in-degrees as the dependent variable, and Twitter followers, friends and number of Twitter statuses as independent variables. Model 2 has the number of network out-degrees as the dependent and number of Twitter followers, friends and number of Twitter statuses as independent variables.

the first model

```
summary(m1 <- glm.nb(INdegrees ~ Followers + Friends + Statuses, data = list_indegrees))
```

converges just fine. But when I run the second model i get the warning message:
`glm.fit: algorithm did not converge`:

```
summary(m2 <- glm.nb(OUTdegrees ~ Followers + Friends + Statuses, data = list_outdegrees))

Call:
glm.nb(formula = OUTdegrees ~ Friends + Statuses + Followers, 
data = list_outdegrees, init.theta = 0.7029123173, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-7.1442  -1.0481  -0.7852  -0.2878  14.6127  

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 4.149e+00  1.022e-02 406.058  < 2e-16 ***
Friends     1.834e-06  4.214e-07   4.353 1.35e-05 ***
Statuses    1.600e-07  1.208e-07   1.325    0.185    
Followers   6.440e-07  8.629e-09  74.639  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.7029) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 22689  on 17244  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 20537  on 17241  degrees of freedom
AIC: 179693

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  0.70291 
      Std. Err.:  0.00653 

2 x log-likelihood:  -179683.26300 
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Also, when I take out `Followers` from the model – it converges, but since `Followers` is an important predictor it wouldn't make any sense to take it out.

This is the first time I'm running negative binomial regression and don't really know what's the deal with the convergence.

Comment: See also http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Marschner.pdf

Comment: @Momo Thanks for the link, I'll read it. Multiplying variables by 100 still does not improve the fit. 
The OUTdegree variable actually doesn't have any zeros in it. It goes from 10 to 321 (M = 76.52; SD = 293.73). Should the absence of zeros be a problem for this model?

Comment: Thanks, no, I don't think the absence of zero is a problem per se. At any rate, diagnostic may be easier if your share more of the data or some exploratory analysis.

Comment: @Momo I'd like to. But to which exploratory analyses are you referring? Or how do I share the data?